# Adding hour string to Datetime PHP

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, time

I am using Laravel to build an application.

I let my users choose both a date and a time in a form using inputs. I save both in two different fields in my database.

The date field is saved as: `2016-06-20`
The time field is saved as: `17:30:00`

Now I would like to combine these two and save them to my database like this: `2016-06-20 17:30:00` so that I can perform some logic on it.

**As I am using Laravel, I thought this would be possible using Carbon but after reading through the documentation several times, I cannot seem to find a way to combine these two.**

Comment: if you are using `mysql` then why you don't use `datetime` type in database?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$date = '2016-06-20';
$time = '17:30:00';
$combinedDateTime = $date . ' ' . $time;
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A T", strtotime($combinedDateTime));
$time =  new \DateTime($time);
```

if you `print_r($time)`, it will show a DateTime object:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2016-06-20 17:30:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a string with both data an then convert to date the string

```
$datetime = $date." ".$time;
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime));
```

Now you can insert this variable into the datetime field of your database

Comment: Ok I might have to update my original question but the case is like this. I receieve a date from my form in a string format. I need to convert this to DateTime or Carbon so I can use modify() or addDay() in while loop to add one day each time the loop iterates. Everytime the loop updates the date, I need to save this new date in my database while adding the time field behind it

Comment: Try doing this: `while(condition){ dateadd($datetime, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days');) }`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean combine the two into a single field in the DB? If so, you don't need any special interface:

```
mysql> create table d (dt datetime, d date, t time);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into d (d, t) values ('2016-06-20', '17:30:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from d;
+------+------------+----------+
| dt   | d          | t        |
+------+------------+----------+
| NULL | 2016-06-20 | 17:30:00 |
+------+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> update d set dt = concat(d, ' ',  t);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from d;
+---------------------+------------+----------+
| dt                  | d          | t        |
+---------------------+------------+----------+
| 2016-06-20 17:30:00 | 2016-06-20 | 17:30:00 |
+---------------------+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This solution seems really nice even though I would prefer to do the logic in PHP instead of a query. I have to admit I am not really sure how to do this in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Use carbon instead of Datetime of php. [click here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for carbon document.

Answer (score 0):

You also can set date and time separately from other DateTime/Carbon objects

```
$source1 = new Carbon('2010-05-16 22:40:10.1');
$dt = new Carbon('2001-01-01 01:01:01.2');
$dt->setTimeFrom($source1);

# echo $dt; // 2001-01-01 22:40:10
```

Or set time (string format) using *setTimeFromTimeString* method.

```
$date = new Carbon('2010-05-16');
$date->setTimeFromTimeString('22:32')

# echo $date; // 2010-05-16 22:32:00
```

More details in [Carbon Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).